# How to call the shell script from any directory and how to call a function without source?

Tags: shell

I want to call my shell script from any directory from my git bash

```
#!/bin/bash


function create() {
    python create.py 
    echo $1
}
```

In my terminal i should be able to call like this:

```
create computers
```

then it should print the statements in my python script and my argument:

```
hello - from my python script
computers - argument
```

[i cannot able to understand what's going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752525/run-bash-script-as-source-without-source-command)

can someone help me how to do this ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not output the first argument inside your Python script? If you did, you could simply put `create.py` in your `$PATH`, add a shebang, and execute it from any directory.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a alias for your script.

In `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias create='source path/to/your/script'
```

This allows to run whatever you want

Comment: what do you mean by ~/.bash_aliases ? can you show it with some example please.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that git bash on windows does not have `.bash_aliases`. But you can add aliases as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104273/how-to-set-aliases-in-the-git-bash-for-windows)